# Using jquery to colour individual table rows onload

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble finding any reference to how this could be done.

I've got a table that loads from an automated csv upload but I need to have the first 3 rows colourised so the 1st row is one colour, the 2nd is another and the 3rd another. It's to help show the 1st place, 2nd place and 3rd place winners in the table.

The rest of the table then needs to have an alternate row colour.

This needs to be done with the onload/document ready and not through any clicking method.

Can someone help?

Comment: Do you really want to use jQuery to do this?  It would be simple enough (and more logical) to use css.

Comment: may b CSS would be a much better option than jQuery..!

Comment: CSS is a great option, so long as the targeted browsers support `nth-child` or the adjacent sibling select.

Comment: Agree, this is the problem as I've checked the stats for the site we're using it on (or planning to) and IE 8 usage is in the top 10 for browser usage. So for that reason IE 8 will need to be considered.

Answer (score 4):

```
$('table > tr:first').css('background-color', 'red');

$('table tr:nth-child(2)').css('background-color', 'blue');

$('table tr:nth-child(3)').css('background-color', 'orange');
```

And for the sake of completeness, here is the CSS which could be used, so long as your targeted browsers support `nth-child` in your selector:

```
 table tr:nth-child(1){ background-color: red; }
 table tr:nth-child(2){ background-color: orange; }
 table tr:nth-child(3){ background-color: blue; }
```

Or using the adjacent sibling selector:

```
 table tr:first-child { background-color: red; }
 table tr:first-child + tr { background-color: orange; }
 table tr:first-child + tr + tr { background-color: blue; }
```

Comment: +1. adjacent sibling selector trick should (almost) work on IE7+.

Comment: Not that I have IE7 kicking around any more to test (thank goodness!), even that browser should work with the adjacent and first-child selectors : http://caniuse.com/css-sel2

Comment: @tewathia: on this page http://quirksmode.org/css/selectors/ the `:first-child` and `+ selector` in IE7 column says "static" i.e. it won't update styles if elements are manipulated via JavaScripe.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jquery to do this, CSS **3** (this means it won't work on IE8 or lower) would work just as well,

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background: #EEEEEE;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #AAAAAA;
}
table tr:nth-child(1) {
    background: red;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) {
    background: blue;
}
table tr:nth-child(3) {
    background: green;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/k6s7b/3/)

Update: IE support can be provided using jQuery:-

```
$('table tr:even').css('background', '#EEEEEE');
$('table tr:odd').css('background', '#AAAAAA');
var rows = $('table tr');
rows.eq(0).css('background', 'red');
rows.eq(1).css('background', 'blue');
rows.eq(2).css('background', 'green');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/k6s7b/6/)

Comment: Looking at the Support table for [`nth-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child), IE8 and Lower do not support this, and with 30% of PC's in the world using Windows XP (with highest IE Support of 8) this is a limited support solution. jQuery offers a wider range of support for this.

Comment: @Nunners Fair point. I've updated my answer to include the jQuery way of doing this as well

Comment: Just to clarify would the jquery solution be for IE only? Or does the jquery cover all browsers but adds the extra support for IE compared to pure css version?

Comment: @Jon It would support all browsers.

Comment: Excellent. Amazing how little code it needs and would never have knew that's how it could have been done. Superb effort everyone and major thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/ARarB/1/)

Use the `:eq()` and the `:gt()` jQuery Selectors. The first 3 rows in the example will be set to green, blue and red.

And then the following set of the rows (Greater Than index 2) will have an alternating colour of Yellow and Gold.

Example :

```
//1st Row
$('#test1 tr:eq(0)').css('background-color', 'green');
//2nd Row
$('#test1 tr:eq(1)').css('background-color', 'blue');
//3rd Row
$('#test1 tr:eq(2)').css('background-color', 'red');

var previousColor = '';
$('#test1 tr:gt(2)').each(function() {
    // All Others
    if (previousColor != 'Gold') {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'Gold');
        previousColor = 'Gold';
    } else {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'Yellow');
        previousColor = 'Yellow';
    }
});
```

Comment: @downvoter, Could you be so kind as to explain why? My solution has a working example and solves the issue.

Comment: Not sure why this would be downvoted, it is indeed another way to skin this cat. I'll upvote for the cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery is inefficient in this case. You can achieve the same effect via css, and use jQuery fallback only for IE8 or older.

```
//first, fourth..
table.colored tr:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    background-color: #aaa
}

//second, fifth...
table.colored tr:nth-of-type(3n+2) {
    background-color: #777
}

//third, sixth
table.colored tr:nth-of-type(3n) {
    background-color: #F00
}
```